# Knockout and jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I currently have the following modal, which is databound using Knockousjs, the data-bind is working fine, but when i try to setup jquery validator, the valid always returns true.

```
    <!-- edit modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editDataClassModal" tabindex="-3" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="with: selectedTag">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="editDataClassForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data Classification</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 paddingTop3">
                                Classification:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" id="txtClassification" name="txtClassification" class="form-control" data-bind="value: copyname" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnCancelEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSaveEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm buttonsize">Save</button>
                    <div class="marginTop10">
                        <span class="label-danger" id="lblErrorEdit" style="display: none;">An error occurred while saving this record.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

and the validator being used:

```
        var edidDataClassValidator = $("#editDataClassForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtClassification: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            txtClassification: {
                minlength: "Classification must consist of at least 2 characters"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (label, element) {
            label.addClass('errorText');
            label.insertAfter(element);
        },
        wrapper: 'span'
    });
```

when the btnSaveEdit button is clicked i run the below:

> ```
>     $(document).on("click", "#btnSaveEdit", function(e) {
>         $("#editDataClassForm").removeAttr("novalidate");
>         var form = $("#editDataClassForm");
>         if (form.valid()) {
>             var itemToEdit = ko.dataFor(this);
>             alert('valid ' + itemToEdit);
>         } else {
>             alert('not valid');
>         }
>         e.preventDefault();
>     });
> ```

If i remove the data-bind from the modal the validator starts working, so i'm assuming it's an issue with jquery validator and knockout?

Comment: Why are you removing the `novalidate` attribute?

Comment: According to this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp using novalidate bypasses the forms' validation.  taking it off lets validation run.

Comment: You are confusing the browser's HTML5 validation and the jQuery Validation plugin.  In fact, the jQuery Validation plugin dynamically ***adds*** the `novalidate` attribute to purposely _disable_ HTML5 validation.  You don't need HTM5 validation interfering with the user experience when you're already using the Validation plugin.

Comment: I see the main issue i was having, I stopped removing the nonvalidate, but that still did not work.  I believe it's an issue with Knockoutjs and Jquery Validate, if I remove the Knockoujs data-bind I have in there the validation kicks in.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it would solve anything.  Just pointing out that removing `novalidate` is pointless.  Have you searched SO yet?  I see a lot of jQuery Validate and Knockout questions.

Comment: I've put your example into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uN2t/) and it appears to be working as expected.  What version of jQuery/jQuery validate/knockout are you using

Comment: I'm using knockout-3.0.0.js I see in the fiddle you are using 3.1.0 I will try to switch to that and see if it helps.